# Day Validation using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use Regex to validate the days in a month. With this i am able to validate 01 to 31. How can i also validate 1-31, so that way i can either have 01 to 31 or 1 to 31

```
(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])
```

Comment: By making `0` optional?

Comment: How would `0?[1-9]` match `0`?

Comment: @SebastianProske: OP does not have a clue, please provide an answer.

Comment: A regex may not be the best solution. In what environment are you trying to validate the days in a month? Many languages have specific date functions which will do that for you.

Comment: I'm trying to use C#, so I thought Regex would be a good choice or maybe using DateTime to also do this.

Comment: The answer marked as duplicate is showing month, day and year. That is not what I wanted. I only wanted the to know how to do with Regex with the specified numbers I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will work for you.
`(([12]\d)|(3[01])|(0?[1-9]))`

I think you didn't understand the way your expression works.

Here it is:
`|` stands for `OR`.
Thus you have 3 cases here:

1. `[12]\d`
2. `3[01]`
3. `0?[1-9]`

1 - match either `1` or `2` as the 1st character and `\d` match any digit (same as [0-9]) as the second character.
2 - match `3` as the 1st digit. And either `0` or `1` as the second one.
3 -  match with any digit between 1 to 9 (both included). `0?` add an optional `0` as the 1st character.

Comment: Its almost there, but it's not true if i type in 10 through 31. it works for 1 through 9 or 01 - 09.

Comment: The order is important. Answer is edited.